# Separate value by thousand + rounding a value

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am using the following code to display a value:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;
$lalageld = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'money', true );
echo $lalageld;
```

It currently returns: 256901.6

However, I need it rounded + separated by thousand like this: 256 901  (and 21009981 = 21 009 981)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$lalageld = number_format($lalageld, 0, '.', ' ');
```

You can read about this function here http://php.net/number_format

Answer (score 0):

number_format() will do it for you.

```
number_format(
    float $number,
    int $decimals = 0,
    string $dec_point = '.',
    string $thousands_sep = ','
)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php